# How can I login and invoke Twitter API in a non-Web-based application?

Tags: twitter, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am looking to integrate Twitter API calls into my standalone Windows App. It is *not* a Web-based application.

As far as I can determine, in order to Login to Twitter and use the API, an app must direct a User to the Twitter Website in a browser to them to login via OAuth and this in turn, after authentication, redirects the User's Browser to a Web page controlled by the application.

Prior to Twitter's swap from Basic Authentication to the OAuth system, it looks like it had previously been possible for a non-web application to simply prompt the User for their User/Password and handle everything via HTTP/REST internally without having to resort to spawning a Web-Browser to complete this process.

Short of writing a vast amount of code to implement a browser within a standalone application to emulate and handle the various OAuth handshakes, is there an easier way by which I can, within a non-web-based application, prompt the User for their Twitter User & Password, perform authentication and start issuing Twitter API calls?

Presumably the Twitter Servers filter HTTP requests on User-Agent and reject any that come from Clients that are not on some internal Twitter-approved list?

I see that there appears to be some form of procedure by which if you divulge all the details of your application and send them a detailed Video of how it all works, then they *may* grant you some form of special access token, However, I am loathe to uncloak my application ahead of release only to have the big boys come along and rip it off and copy the idea before it can gain traction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [PIN-based authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based). This is for a applications which are not web based and cannot embed a web browser. I haven't used it myself, but it looks quite straightforward -at least, once you have oauth working.

That is, assuming that it is acceptable for your target users to open a browser and go to Twitter to fetch the PIN. They don't specify how long the pin is valid for, but it seems there is a mechanism to revoke the PIN.

You don't specify which technology you are using. If you have technical problems when implementing it, pls post them.

Comment: Many thanks for the information. So, again a browser is needed for the User to Login to Twitter and text has to be copied and pasted.   Is there no alternate way that can be easily totally automated to avoid further User interaction, short of implenting a browser emulation in code to capture all of the above?

Comment: My previous comments were not too accurate, I've removed them. Anyhow, my guess is that if you have a setup with a web browser and oauth which is working, you could replicate the same HTTP request and build them up on your code. However, this would be a against oauth philosophy (and maybe even a security breach). Doing it without oauth, you would be asking the user to give away their twitter password to your app. Oauth way, the user only gives his twitter password to Twitter.

Comment: Thanks. It would be a shame if there was no direct access since this is the way that Twitter built up their business in the first place, only to pull up the drawbridge behind them. In theory, any HTTP client would be as good as any other, but I suspect that there is more to it than that and I also suspect that non-approved User Agents get rejected.